# I get partial string when I send compressed string via CURL?

Tags: php, string, curl, compression

I have a script on my local server. That script sends via CURL (POST) some data compressed with gzip to the live server which then uncompresses it and stores it in file.

Everything works when I send it to one live server, but on another live server, if I compress the string, I get only part of it. I tried to use encryption instead of compression and the problem is the same. It only works when string is "untouched".

The two live servers are at two different hosting companies and they have different configurations, I suspect that is the reason for my problem, but I'm not sure what part of the config the reason is. I tried with small (40 kb compressed) string, so execution time and memmory aren't the problem. POST size is 8MB on both servers.

Does anybody have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I was going to say that it sounds like the second server has a limit on the size of POST data. But then it wouldn't work with the uncompressed string, either -- that would be even larger.

Comment: I would like to update my situation.... I tried to encode compressed and encrypted string in base64 and now it works... but still I don't understand why... because on another server it works fine without the need for encapsulation in base64 encoding .

it's a workaround, not a solution because, because the data that has to be sent gets bigger 

so still, if somebody knows the reason for the above problem, i would appriciate it.

Comment: Sounds like the file is being uploaded with encoding application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of multipart/form-data, and the binary file isn't being encoded properly. Can you show your code? See the PHP manual entry for `curl_setopt` for information on how to get each encoding.

Comment: you need to add the code how you send the POST request and how you prepare the data.

Comment: Are the operating systems the exact same on the two different servers?

Comment: Can you contact the host companies? This is the type of thing they are paid to help you with.

Comment: If you're sending it exactly the same way to both servers then the error is on the other server end. Are they both receiving it the same way? If you hit a redirect one server (with a 302 for example) but not the other you could be having multiple url-encoding issues. Did you just straight dump the received POST where it doesn't arrive right? What specifically looks wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

wireshark is the way to go; it'll show you what's going on the wire.